# Best way to perform CONTAINS with Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

Could anyone give me an advice on how to perform CONTAINS search with Lucene? While using WildcardQuery is much more expensive. Could I use FILTER instead of WildcardQuery?

Thanks a lot for your supporting.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Behe: Currently, I have no clue on how to use FILTER instead of WildcardQuery. An example just appeared in my head is that I will search all documents then do filtering on what condition that I need. Do you have any idea about performing CONTAINS with Lucene without using WildcardQuery?

Comment: Could you give a simple example what your problem is? It would be helpful if you could give documents and a certain query and what your expected hits are.